# Using stack Navigator with imported component React-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am pretty new to react-native and I have been trying out navigation.
I have 4 component classes each in its own .js file.
App.js imports the stackNavigator.
Movies.js imports another component called MoviePopup.js.
MoviePopup.js has a button which I want to click to open a Confirmation Screen (Confirmation.js) and also pass a random code.

Inside App.js I setup the stackNavigator as follows:

```
const TicketsApp = StackNavigator({
  Movies: { screen: MoviesList },
  Confirmation: { screen: Confirmation },
});
```

Application navigates well to movies page.
Inside movies I wrote a funtion bookTicket() as follows:

```
bookTicket = () => {
  if (!this.state.chosenTime) {
  Alert.alert('Book Movie Error', 'Please select show time');
  } else {
    this.closeMovie();//close popup

    //I am supposed to navigate to comfirmation window here 
    //and pass a booking code as a prop to the confirmation window
    //What code should I use here to make my navigation work
  }
}
```

I am unable to navigate to navigate to confirmation page at that point. bookTicket() function is passed as a prop to Moviepopup.js as the 'onBook' function and called on the onPress method of button inside Moviepopup.js as follows:

```
<TouchableHighlight
   underlayColor="#9575CD"
   style={styles.buttonContainer}
   onPress={onBook} >

   <Text style={styles.button}>Book My Tickets</Text>

</TouchableHighlight>
```

I need help writing the bookTicket function for the navigation to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just call onBook like that, you need to get it from the props of your component:

```
 onPress={this.props.onBook}
```

This should do the work. If not, we will need to see more code

To pass props to another screen when you click on a button, you just have to do:

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('YourPageName', {someProp: 'propContent'})}
```

For more informations about how to work with navigators you should go on the [React Navigation doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack)

Comment: Thanks got what I was missing.